# How can I find a contributor to help my organization with an urgent/difficult upgrade?

Tags: upgrade

We are a global NGO based in Costa Rica and I haven't been able to find an expert to help us upgrading our CiviCRM System.
We are now using CiviCRM 4.7.23. and have a new site on Wordpress. We haven't updated it because we haven't found someone to safely transfer our old data to a newer version. 
We need help!

Answer (score 2):

Javiera welcome to CiviCRM stackexchange, [You can find experts](https://civicrm.org/partners-contributors) on CiviCRM website or drop a message on [CiviCRM mattermost channel](https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm/channels/dev).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried ['Find an Expert'](https://civicrm.org/partners-contributors) on CiviCRM.Org?